# Variable Does Not Exist Error for a Nested Query in Apex

Tags: apex, csv

I am getting this error with this class. Variable does not exist for Subject, ActivityDate, ActivitySubType, and Status.

[image]

```java
public class ExportActivityHistory {
    public static void  fetchActivityRecords(){
        Set<Id> allIds = new Set<Id> {'axxxxxxxxxxxxxx','axxxxxxxxxxxxxx'};
        List<Contact> allCon = [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Subject, ActivityDate, ActivityType, ActivitySubtype, Description, Status, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy.Name FROM ActivityHistories ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC, LastModifiedDate DESC) FROM Contact WHERE Id = :allIds];
        System.debug('Size: '+allCon.size()); //Check if you're getting the right number
                                             
        //Send the CSV file via E-mail
        String myHeader = 'Id, Name, Subject, ActivityDate, ActivityType, ActivitySubtype, Description, Status, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy.Name';
        String fnlHeader = myHeader;
                                             
        for(Contact aff : allCon){
            String recString = aff.Id + ',' + aff.Name + ',' + aff.Subject + ',' +
                + aff.ActivityDate + ',' + aff.ActivitySubtype + ',' +  
                + aff.Description + ',' + aff.Status + ',' + 
                ',' + aff.CreatedDate + ',' + aff.CreatedBy.Name + ',' 
                + aff.LastModifiedDate + ',' + aff.LastModifiedBy.Name + '\n';
                fnlHeader = fnlHeader + recString;
        }
                                             
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment csvAttc = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(fnlHeader);
        string csvname = 'ActivityHistory.csv';
        csvAttc.setFileName(csvname);
        csvAttc.setBody(csvBlob);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new list<string> {'test@gmail.com'};
        String subject = 'Activity history Export From Anonymous Apex!!!';
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        email.setPlainTextBody('Activity history Export!!');
        email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{csvAttc});
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
    } 
}
```

Comment: I've made changes to the code formatting (so it's readable and consistent) that may affect the line numbers that the errors appear on. It does appear to be in the same ballpark though. I've also left in a syntax error right near the beginning of the provided code (the initialization of `allIds` is missing a semicolon at the end of the line).

Comment: Thanks for flagging that! It was typo.

Answer (score 0):

Those particular fields are on the `ActivityHistory` records, not the `Contact` record that you're iterating over.

When you have a parent-child subquery (i.e. a subquery in the `SELECT` clause of the main query), that results in a list of child records being embedded into each parent record.

Nested data structures effectively mean that you need a nested loop to process them. That's because there can be more than one `ActivityHistory` on a given `Contact`.

Off the top of my head, the way I would approach this is to:

- declare a list of strings outside of all loops, put your header data into it
- loop over the `Contact`s
- loop over each `Contact`'s `ActivityHistories`
- declare a list of strings in the nested loop, add the Id/Name from the `Contact` (the loop variable for your Contact is still "in scope" in the nested loop) and all of your target fields from the ActivityHistory
- use `String.join()` to put commas between each field value, then add that to the list outside of all loops
- once out of the loops, use `String.join()` again to put newlines between each row of the csv data

e.g.

```
List<String> csvRows = new List<String>();
// Add the header
csvRows.add('Id, Name, ..., LastModifiedBy.Name');

for(Contact cont : contactList) {
    // Nested loop over child records from the subquery
    for(ActivityHistory history : cont.ActivityHistories) {
        List<String> singleRow = new List<String> {
            // You can access stuff from the outer loop in the inner loop
            cont.Id, cont.Name,
            // Subject, ActivityDate, etc... are on the _history_ record
            //   rather than the contact record.
            history.Subject, history.ActivityDate, ..., history.LastModifiedBy.Name
        };

        // Use string.join() to avoid having to do the string concatenation yourself
        //   (which is more prone to errors)
        // You may want to consider enclosing data in double quotes
        String completeRow = String.join(singleRow, ',');

        // Add the result to the outer list
        csvRows.add(completeRow);
    }
}

// String.join() to add a newline after each row (except the last)
String completeCSV = String.join(csvRows, '\n');
```

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for your help! this worked, I also had to convert ActivityDate to a  string and that resolved the error. However, the CSV file formatting is a bit off. The Description notes are spreading across multiple lines, causing data disruptions. Any ideas on how to fix this and ensure all Description notes for each record are contained in a single cell? Thanks again!

Comment: @SFIDK You need to surround the data in the Description field with double quotes (and escape any double quotes in the Description). That's the way CSV handles things like having commas and newlines in a single cell. `String.escapeCsv()` does that.

Comment: that worked like a charm. Thanks a lot! Appreciate the help.

Comment: it seems that with a diffrent set of Ids, I get a 'System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object' error. Any idea why that might be? Thanks again.

Comment: @SFIDK This is getting close to "make a new question" territory. Null Pointer Exceptions (NPEs) happen when you try to use dot notation on something that's `null`. If your `ActivityHistory` doesn't have a Description, then `history.Description.escapeCsv()` would lead to that. You'd probably want to use the Safe Navigation Operator, `?.` to handle the potential null data. E.g. `history.Description?.escapeCsv()`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked.